# Is there a version of closing lemma in the case of uniform space?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, uniform-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{U})$ be a uniform space and $f:X\to X$ be a homeomorphism. For symmetric element $A\in\mathcal{U}$, let $A(f)$ be the set of all homeomorphisms $g:X\to X$ such that $(g(x), f(x))\in A$ for all $x\in X$.

The point $x\in X$ is a non-wandering point of $f$, $x\in\Omega(f)$, if for all $D\in \mathcal{U}$ there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^n(D[x])\cap D[x]\neq \emptyset$.

Let $\mathcal{N}(f)$ be the set $x\in X$ such that for every $A\in \mathcal{U}$, there is $g\in A(f)$ such that $x\in Per(g)$.

What is the relation between $\mathcal{N}(f)$ and $\Omega(f)$?

Comment: Does $Per$ mean '*periodic* points', i.e. those for which $g^n(x)=x$ for some $n$?

Comment: @Berci, Yes. $Per(g)=\{x\in X|  g^n(x)=x, g^i(x)\neq x, \forall 0<i<n\}$